# Xcode: Move image (Quartzcore) + running 2 IBActions, one immediately after the other in 1 click with time respected

Tags: ios, xcode, core-animation, quartz-core

I have a question regarding Xcode. 
I found a tutorial on the net that allowed me to move an image around the screen. 
Could you please explain how I can make my button move to the left **and back to right** with one click (I can't find this anywhere...), and immediately after that run another IBAction that allows me to switch to another subview? (I already have this code naturally...). I tried to add both IBActions in 1 centralized one, but it didn't seem to work :-( It opens in this case immediately the subview without showing me the animation.

What I tried:

The code obtained until now:

```
-(IBAction) aMove: (id) sender{

    if (bMove == NO) {

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        btnTarget.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-30,0);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        bMove = YES;

    }else{

        btnTarget.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        bMove = NO;

    }

}

-(IBAction) aAnimateActivate: (id) sender {

    [self aMove:nil];
    [self targetOpenView:nil]; //Opens the subview

}
```

I appreciate your help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

concatenate works to combine animations and I just put two blocks of animations (two of the one shown below) after each other... :

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1),CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(10, -50));       
btnGuide.transform = transform;
[btnGuide setAlpha:0.0];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Basically implementing this code did the trick... Easy! 
However... I needed some additional pieces of code for the further implementation such as:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(aGuide) withObject:self afterDelay:0.0];
```

(don't mind the selector name) 
and:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.5 target:self selector:@selector(targetOpenView:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at all of your program flow nor doing any actual testing (and I find when using Core Animation that the only way to be sure it works right is to code it and see if it does) the problem with the subview opening right away occurs because right after you invoke your `"aMove"` method to set up the first animation the thread continues with the next line of code, i.e., the `[self] targetOpenView:nil` statement, which immediately opens the subview and thus doesn't allow the first animation sequence to be shown.  **There is no pause to wait for the first animation to be completed.**  The animation, once commited, runs on its own thread while your code continues to run on the current thread (probably the application's main thread).  That might not seem to be the most sensible way but you have to think of the code you write as the process to set up an animation that, once committed, is a separate entity that is free to run on its own (beside your code).  The advantage to Apple's implementation is that you can set up a whole bunch of different animations which occur at the same time.  One of Core Animation's design goals is to take away the need for the programmer to be handling all the starting and stopping of various animations and instead let the animation coordination be done using various methods of *delay* and *duration* or providing the means for one animations events to be observed (and acted upon) by other animations.

In order to do the animation(s) the way you want you will need use a method which only allows the second animation to begin once the first is over.  One way (assuming that the subview change would be set up as an animation itself) is to use a `completion:` handler, an animation block that only begins upon completion of the first animation.  Another way is to let the two animations "start together" but include a `delay:` parameter in the second animation that is equal to the length of the first animation.  If the subview change is not done with an animation but is just done with code in the main thread then you need to set up a an *animation delegate* that is called when certain events occur in your animation, one of which is it's completion.  Parameter(s) are passed to your delegate to tell you what is occurring and to which animation.

All of this is discussed, with examples, in the *Animations* section of the *View Programming Guide to iOS* (about 10 pages that will probably show you almost exactly how to do what you want):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6

Also, in order to set up the first animation to move the button somewhere and back again you might want to read the subtopic in that same section of the guide mentioned above: *Implementing Animations That Reverse Themselves*.  I think it would be the cleanest way to do what you want.

(FYI, I'm better with the MacOS side of Core Animation than the iOS side but the "why did this happen immediately?" problem you have is a common pitfall when getting up to speed with how it works.  Hope this explanation helps.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input! Indeed, I started reading some courses about Core animation (no easy stuff to get what you actually want sometimes) and I got in contact with the "delay" and "duration" methods that may give me what I need. I will also check out the "Reverse" method you mentioned in your explanations. Honestly, I had thought about a possibility like "delay" before, but it seemed strange and I feared that it could provide potential problems (such as, what if the system screws the timing due to eg. the fact that the memory is low in resources?

Comment: I don't know if that is even possible though but it seems logical). I feel it a little bit as a pity that you cannot just decide to "first I do this" and "then I do that" (like in VBA :-)). But I suppose it's just something to get used to. I will read the link you sent to me; thank you for that and for your exhaustive explanations on the topic! To let you in on my idea; I have an Apple-dock-menu-like menu bar with five buttons.

Comment: I wanted to generated a kind of "trigger" effect on a button; when you click it, it makes a "tsjak" sound like a trigger, and then the button moves slightly into the background (becomes smaller) while the color gets slightly darker as well. Well, hope I'll get there ;-)